# Is it possible to edit AWS Lambda layer code in the console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there a way to edit an AWS Lambda layer's code in console?

Is it possible to update the layer's code in the console just like the lambdas?

Answer (score 8):

no, layers are ZIP only.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Comment: So I can't mock function and can't use the console to edit. Therefore I've to do "amplify push" every time to test. :(

Comment: Although I've found a workaround to mock lambda layers for using VS code debugger.